# pthread_detach() causes SIGSEGV on 64 bit Linux

Tags: linux, multithreading, pthreads, x86-64, segmentation-fault

Here is a description of my situation: I have to take care of the bug in our product. The thread is created as `joinable` , it must do its work, terminate and nobody will call `pthread_join()` for it. So the thread is created with JOINABLE attribute (by default) and before termination it calls the next code:

```
{  pthread_detach(pthread_self()); pthread_exit(NULL); }
```

It works like a charm on all 32 bit linux distros I met, but it causes `SIGSEGV` on 64 bit distros (Ubuntu 13.04 x86_64 and Debian). I didn't try with Slackware. Here is a core:

```
Core was generated by `IsaVM -s=1 -PrjPath="/home/taf/Linux_Fov_540148/Cmds"  -stgMode=1 -PR -Failover'.
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00007f5911a7c009 in pthread_detach () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007f5911a7c009 in pthread_detach () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x000000000041310d in _kerCltDownloadThr (StartParams=0x6bfce0 <RESFOV>) at ./dker0clt.c:1258
#2  0x00007f5911a7ae9a in start_thread () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#3  0x00007f591159f3fd in clone () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#4  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

I figured out how to fix this bug - I set CREATE_DETACHABLE attribute (with `pthread_attr_setdetachstate()`) for the thread before it is created and it works as expected.

But my question - is it a crime to call this code?

```
{  pthread_detach(pthread_self()); pthread_exit(NULL); }
```

Does `pthread_detach()` do something asynchronously after call and that causes `pthread_exit()` to bring problems? But the crash point is `pthread_detach()` not `pthread_exit()`! I don't understand the reason for this crash completely! Why does it work on 32 bits? Is it a race condition somewhere in the `pthread` implementation?

`pthread_join()` doesn't called for this thread.

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finished my research with approaches offered by a respectable @MaximYegorushkin. `AddressSanitizer` shows me one buffer obverflow in our product but it isn't related to my problem (I will definitely fix it later, it is always good to have such a wise tool to hunt the bugs). So decided to override all necessary `pthread_xxx` functions with `LD_PRELOAD` method. I run a simple test to be sure my library works as expected:

```
[HACK] Loading pthread hack.
Starting thread...!
[HACK] pthread_create: thread=7FAC6C86D700
Waiting for 2 seconds...
[HACK] pthread_self: thread=7FAC6C86D700
thread_func: thread id = 7FAC6C86D700
Thread: sin(3.26) = -0.121109
[HACK] pthread_self: thread=7FAC6C86D700
[HACK] pthread_detach: thread=7FAC6C86D700
Terminating...
```

All strings started from **[HACK]** are produced by my `threadhack.so` library. 
Then I run my project with this library it points me exactly where the problem is:

Code executed: `{  pthread_detach(pthread_self()); pthread_exit(NULL); }`

Debug traces:

```
[HACK] pthread_create: thread=7F403251CB00
.....
[HACK] pthread_self: thread=7F403251CB00  
[HACK] pthread_detach: thread=3251CB00
```

So we see that `pthread_self` returns a good thread id, but `pthread_detach` received it already mangled (cut to 32 bit). How could this be? I generated assembler code for both my simple working test application as a reference and for my project:

**Reference application:**

```
call    pthread_self
movq    %rax, %rdi
call    pthread_detach
movl    $0, %edi
call    pthread_exit
```

So we see here that `movq` instruction is used to copy 64 bit thread id (`movq    %rax, %rdi`). OK, check what GCC generated **for my project**:

```
movl    $0, %eax
call    pthread_self
movl    %eax, %edi
movl    $0, %eax
call    pthread_detach
movl    $0, %edi
movl    $0, %eax
call    pthread_exit
```

Woa! We have two `movl` instructions (32 bit), one copies the least significant 32 bits (`movl    %eax, %edi`) and instead of most significan part it always put zero! (`movl    $0, %eax`). So this is a reason for the mangled thead id. I have no idea why the code is so different - compilation flags are the same. I saw this bug in `GCC 4.7` I see this bug in `GCC 4.8` (Latest package from the `Ubuntu 13.10 x86_64`).

So at least now I see what hapenning. Thanks to @Maxim and brilliant tools. I learned a new thing again.

P.S. I don't know how to submit a bug report to the GCC team. I can't reproduce the problem on a small simple application and I can't hand them my project because it is a proprietary software and I'm NDA-ed to not distribute it.

Comment: I can't do this, I'm under NDA. I can probably publish only the problem function from which pthread_self() is called. Is there a way to send private messages here?

Comment: Just the function which you disassembled. But I see you accepted your own answer, so you must have solved your problem and don't require any more help )

Comment: The solution for my problem was to create thread with detached attribute. Not to detach inside of the thread. But my boss blocked this fix and I had to find the reason of the crash. Now I see the reason, I have a solution - so problem is solved.

Comment: Flags used to compile the code:    `CC = gcc -c -g3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -O0 -fstack-usage -fstack-protector-all -fsanitize=address $(CC_INCLUDE) $(CC_DEFINES)`    `LK_END = -lm -lpthread -lrt -lasan`

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin here is [C source](http://pastebin.com/EiMN4qtr) problem at the line 108, here is [assembler output](http://pastebin.com/BuaEp3bZ) problem at the line 954. This paste will expire in 1 day.

Comment: So technically speaking I know where is the problem now, I see bad code generated by GCC and I know how avoid this crash (use detached attribute). But honestly I'm doubt too that GCC generated the bad code.  I more easily belive I use wrong compilation flags, bad options or something like that =)

Comment: You should use `-pthread` gcc flag both when compiling and linking. `-lpthread` is not sufficient and not necessary. And it looks like your reference application is 64-bit and the original one is 32-bit...

Comment: Both of them are built using the options I showed above. Both of them are native 64 bit applications built on 64 bit OS. I tried with `-pthread` flag and it doesnt change anything for me - `movl` instruction is used to copy 32 bits of `pthread_self()` result. The `file` utility says: `ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=0xef54c4160d386b056bcf893907738018e3d4e1fd, not stripped`. `sha1` isdifferent of course but other from that all of them reported as 64 bit code

Answer (score 1):

A thread detaching itself does not feel right. It is normally responsibility of the thread that called `pthread_create()` which can create a detached thread if necessary.

It could be that the thread has already been detached. Because attempting to detach an already detached thread results in unspecified behaviour.

My top wild guesses would be:

1. The thread gets detached more than once. As a quick check I would try setting a breakpoint on `pthread_detach` in `gdb` to see whether duplicate thread ids gets passed in this function. If it is difficult to run your application under `gdb`, another option is to override `pthread_create` and `pthread_detach` and track thread ids to detect double detach. See http://hackerboss.com/overriding-system-functions-for-fun-and-profit/
2. Memory corruption. `valgrind` may help you detect memory corruption if it is possible to run your application under it. Alternatively, try instrumenting your application with run-time error checks by compiling with `-fstack-protector-all`, `-fsanitize=address`, `-fsanitize=thread` if you use `gcc`. `clang` compiler also have an array of options to detect such errors, see sanitizers on http://clang.llvm.org/docs/index.html.

Comment: pthread_detach manual [link](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_detach.3.html) says in the example section:   The following statement detaches the calling thread:

           pthread_detach(pthread_self());

Comment: @OlegOsovitskiy It does, but it does not make it a good design example though.

Comment: When I try to create a small program doing exactly the same thing detach self + exit immediately - I can't reproduce this bug anymore - it works as expected. It only happens in a big project

Comment: @OlegOsovitskiy It is the first time ever a test program behaves differently from another program, is it not? )

Comment: No it not the first time =)  I run my test program through a valgrind - no warnings. I will try to run the big project, but there is a lot of conditions and dependencies how to run a VM, so it could be a challenging task. The bug is fixed, but I'm afraid that this bug is somewhere else and it just revealed on pthread_detach()

Comment: @OlegOsovitskiy I agree that the cause of the error is likely to be somewhere else. Added a few options for you to try.

Comment: Thank you very much. My Ubuntu 13.04 had GCC 4.7 but the features you mentioned are introduced from GCC 4.8. So I updated my system to Ubuntu 13.10. `ThreadSanitizer` crashes into SIGSEGV right in `__tsan_init` function. But `AddressSanitizer` works as expected, it shows me that indeed there is a memory corruption. I'm working to find it. I will try your suggested trick with function overriding also - seems very useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you don't have the prototype for either pthread_detach or pthread_self in the code that invokes pthread_detach(pthread_self());  Without the prototype, the compiler will assume the argument is int (pthread_detach) or that the function returns an int (pthread_self).

Although thinking it through further, I'm more suspecting that pthread_self is the culprit being either undefined (returning an int) or defined incorrectly as returning an int.  The compiler then correctly extends this to a 64 bit integer by adding the leading 32 bits of zero.

Comment: Please add a solution in addition to guesses of the cause, unless I'm misreading the question or just don't know enough about the subject to know what I'm talking about, which is possible.